# How to scrape Multiple Pages used pagenation link using node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to scrape website in that there is 1000 list is having with pagenation,how to get all data with the help of pagenation url using node.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a module that do precisely that, but I am not aware of it.
You can locate the pagination link and make the scraping module, that you use, to scrape the next page as well. 
It is far easier if the pagination is accessible via URL and is easy to describe (domain.page/2, domain.page/3, ...). 
If the next page is accessible only after clicking, with no change in the URL, then you can use libraries such as phantom.js or casper.js, which are used commonly for testing.